# Escape command in a vimscrimpt

Tags: command, vim

Can anyone help me how to put an `<esc>` command in a vimscript in order to switch from a insert visual mode (selection mode) to the visual mode?

This is my script:

```
  if a:type == "'<,'>" 
    normal! "\<esc>\<esc>"
    normal gvy
    let myvariable= @+
  endif
```

**explication**:
I have selected a piece of text. (I'm now in *insert visual mode* (=selection mode))
I have to select the same text in *visual mode*.
Without vimscript I just have to push 2 times the `<esc>` command and the command `gv` in normal mode to reselect the selection again and this time I'm in *visual mode*.

I tried to put the `<esc>` commands as in above script but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have completely wrong syntax for invocation of `:normal`.

```
normal! "\<Esc>\<Esc>"
```

will execute 14 characters in normal mode, none of them will be escape character: normal does not accept expressions. You have to use

```
execute "normal! \e\e"
```

(`\<Esc>` also works, but `\e` is faster to type). I see no reason in having two normal commands here so

```
execute "normal! \e\egvy"
```

. But I am still wondering what you do to invoke this script? Without this information the above is likely to prove being completely useless.

PS: I completely agree with @romainl that using easy mode and, more, using mouse in easy mode is completely wrong way of using vim.

Comment: Thank you Zyx. I use the windows mode of gvim, that means that when I select text (in insert mode) it doesn't go in visual mode but insert visual mode (=selection mode). I find that easier then visual mode. But I have a big vimscript which works fine in visual mode (after I leave insert mode and select some stuff), but sometimes I forget to leave insert mode and select text to use it with the vimscript, it gives an error, so I would try to make this vimscript also work when I I'm in insert visual mode. Now it does. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

What are you doing in *insert visual mode* in the first place? Are you using GVim in "easy" mode and using the mouse? There are *better* ways…

Anyway, instead of `<Esc><Esc>` you can use `<C-g>` to go from *select* mode to *visual* mode.

Without more background on your goal I can't be sure but I think that you are doing something unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Romainl, thank you for answering. Yes I use gvim in "easy mode" I believe. (`set mouse=a` / `set selection=inclusive`). `<C-g>` doesn't work btw. It inserts `<C-g>` in the text.

Comment: Do you mean that hitting Ctrl + g actually inserts `<C-g>`? That's weird!

Comment: yep it inserts `<C-g>` in the text.